# Package Cache error in Unity rendering cloned project unusable

Tags: unity

I recently cloned a repository from GitHub, the project is fully functional and up to date on my friend's system, but when I clone the repository I get these compiler errors which need to be resolved, but I have no concept of how to fix an error of this type in code I have not written myself, as it appears to be compiler errors in part of unity's GUI?

[image]

Library\Package\Cache\com.unity.ugui@1.0.0\Runtime\UI\Core\DefaultControls.cs(557, 105): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Dropdown' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Library\Package\Cache\com.unity.ugui@1.0.0\Runtime\UI\Core\DefaultControls.cs(637, 13): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Dropdown' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Library\Package\Cache\com.unity.ugui@1.0.0\Runtime\UI\Core\DefaultControls.cs(637, 51): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Dropdown' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Library\Package\Cache\com.unity.ugui@1.0.0\Runtime\UI\Core\DefaultControls.cs(646, 38): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Dropdown' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Library\Package\Cache\com.unity.ugui@1.0.0\Runtime\UI\Core\DefaultControls.cs(647, 38): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Dropdown' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Library\Package\Cache\com.unity.ugui@1.0.0\Runtime\UI\Core\DefaultControls.cs(648, 38): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Dropdown' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling the Unity UGUI package via the Package Manager, or rebuilding your project files?

Comment: I just tried reinstalling and that didn't make a difference. I'm not sure how to rebuild project files so I'm looking how to do that right now.